# Why does some code have to be placed in the header or functions.php instead of any other php file to work properly?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This question is not help on a code, just want to understand why I have to add functions etc in the functions.php or header.php of Wordpress instead of any other php file that I have created? (As far as I’ve tested  all php inside a plugin that has been activated works)

However, when I introduce some JavaScript in my plugin php file, my style went abnormal, but when I add it to the header.php file, it all works well. Why is that and how can I make it so my plugin has a similar effect as when the  is in the header.php?

Thanks, this is to understand, I’m a noob. 
This is the current culprit

```
echo “<script>jscode = ‘test’;</script>“
```

Comment: Unless you're using a framework there are no restrictions on naming your php files. Can you post a minimal reproducible example of your issue? Edit: noticed your wordpress tag, this is why, wordpress is restricting you, you could probably find a way around it if you looked for it.

Comment: Without seeing some actual code to understand what's confusing you and actually provide some sort of explanation, all we can do here is speculate (which, IMO, it's not what this site is for). As Shard said before, please share your code so we can help.

Comment: I added a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The standards of adding code to the `functions.php` and to a lesser extent `header.php` (many times, it's better to add code in `functions.php` on hook it into the head via a hook like [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) or [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts))

Adding code to the `functions.php` is due in part to how WordPress is set up. It comes down to two primary principles. First, the `functions.php` file is [always loaded](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) while that theme is active. The second part is that WordPress functions by firing off a series of [Action Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) (and, less related to this, [filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)).

It's largely a way to normalize theme development, but it's by no means a hard and fast rule that PHP needs to go in your `functions.php` file, and your actual implementation will actually vary largely whether you're developing a [SaaS Solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service), a Theme, a Plugin, or just developing a client's website.

For Example:

## Theme Developement:

JS and CSS are typically written, added to a `/theme-name/assets/[css:js]` type directory, and then enqueued (aka "loaded") to the header or footer by using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook and [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) functions. This allows your theme's end-users to modify, extend, or remove (dequeue) these assets programatically - and gives them a semantic way to do so. This typically looks something like:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_assets' );
function load_assets(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/my-css.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/my-js.js', array(), false, true );
}
```

Now end users can target `my-style` and `my-script` with the [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/), [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/), or [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) type functions. Or even programatically remove them with [`wp_dequeue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/) and [`wp_dequeue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/).

## Plugin Development:

Your `functions.php` file in a theme is similar to a plugin file. In a plugin, the core file will function similarly, and you'll still use hooks like you do in Theme Development. It's even **more** important to use appropriate hooks here because you don't have direct access to the theme's `header.php` or `functions.php` file - so you'll be hooking and unhooking functionality with [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) and [`remove_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/) instead of "baking in" code directly to the header and footer.

## Software as a Service

This varies LARGELY on what your target software will do. Many times a function that's necessary regardless of themes or plugins will be added as a [Must-Use Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) which is always loaded regardless of what's active or the current request. Again, while you may control the theme in this application it may change over time, so it may not make sense to add "global, always needed" functions to the theme's `functions.php` file - as you'll need to move/copy/modify that code if and when you decide to update the theme.

## Modifying a client's website

Again, adding code to this will vary largely - but typically you will be adding code to the `functions.php` of the active theme.

## Conclusion:

There's no hard and fast rule that says "PHP code will only work in the functions.php file" - as long as you properly include/require/hook in your files, they will fire. As for adding CSS and JavaScript - please do yourself, your colleagues, and most importantly **your future self** a favor and properly enqueue them with the `functions.php`, a Must-Use Plugin, a plugin's core file, or even another `asset manager` PHP class.

In regards to your edit, you're using true quotes, drop those. Replace `echo “<script>jscode = ‘test’;</script>“` with `echo "<script>var jscode = "test";</script>;` (you're not initializing your JS variable, and you're not closing your `echo` line with a semi-colon). Even then it should be either 1) localized into another script, 2) hooked into the `wp_head()` or `wp_footer()`, or 3) added to it's own `.js` file and properly enqueued into the header or footer. Baking in JS and CSS is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Wow. Very detailed. As I’m developing this plugin (JavaScript var will hold current_user) to I feel that it is redundant to add it to the functions.php. This plugin should work right out of the plugin php, as I’m going to be using on different sites

Comment: It's redundant and _flawed_ to add it to your `functions.php` if you're developing a plugin - since your plugin has zero control over the currently active theme of any individual site. Just add it in your plugin's main file and all should be well!

Comment: I wish it worked that way but for me it skewed the images. Wonder why.

Comment: We'll need a live example or enough code to show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Based on the one snippet you posted, both the JS and PHP are invalid.